# How to store point values of a triange in a point array to sort them afterwards?

Tags: arrays, sorting, points

I have started to do some Java exercises and now I am trying to find the longest side of a given object (i.e. triangle). In the code below, I tried to put a triangle's coordinates in a point array and try to put it on the screen to further develop the algorithm and try to sort them. Could anyone please help me understand how to use point arrays? Seems like i am missing lots of fundamental knowledge on the topic.

```
public void getLargestSide() {
    // Put code here
    FileResource fr = new FileResource();
    Shape k = new Shape(fr);
    Point prevPt = k.getLastPoint();
    
    int z = getNumPoints(k);
    double[] a = new double[z];
    //Point currPt : k.getPoints() - For loop 
            
    for (int i= 0; i<z; i++)
        {
        //currPt = k.getPoints();
        Point[] currPt = new Point [z];
        currPt[] = k.getPoints();
        double dist = prevPt.distance(currPt[i]);
        a[i] = dist;
        System.out.println(prevPt + "-" + currPt);
        System.out.println("Distance is:" + a[i]);
        System.out.println("i is:" + i);
        System.out.println("   ");
        System.out.println("Current Point Is:" + currPt);
        System.out.println("   ");
        prevPt = currPt[i];
    }
    
    //System.out.println(prevPt);
    
    return ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there i finally solved it.

```
    public double getLargestSide(Shape s) {
    
    Point prevPt = s.getLastPoint();
    int i = 0;
    int z = getNumPoints(s);
    Point[] a = new Point[z];
    double[] b = new double[z];
    double max = b[i]; 

    for (Point currPt : s.getPoints()) {
        // Find distance from prevPt point to currPt 
        b[i] = prevPt.distance(currPt);
        // Update prevPt to be currPt
        prevPt = currPt;
        a[i] = currPt;
        i= i + 1;    
        
        for(int j=0; j<z; j++)
        {
            if (b[j]>max)
            {
                max = b[j];
            }
        }
      
                               
    }
    return max;
}
```